# File not created

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am using firebase download and File.createTempFile for downloading files. The onSuccess Method logs the message but it doesn't create the downloaded file..This is my code

```
 public void downloadFile(){
    StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child("mountains.jpg");
    File localFile = null;
    try {
        localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                  Log.i("msg","ok");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
            Log.i("msg", exception.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

}

Comment: did you check your permissions?

Comment: yes i did add permission. 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>